# In Django serializer, how do I serialize both sides of a foreign key relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my Django code, I have this model:

```
class Swipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        related_name='swipes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        default=None
    )

    SWIPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "left"),
        (2, "right"),
        (3, "up"),
        (4, "down")
    )

    direction = models.IntegerField(
        choices = SWIPE_CHOICES
    )
```

where Profile is my user class. I have a view to display all profiles:

```
class ProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

where ProfileSerializer looks like:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    # serializations of other fields

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'url', 'id', 'username', 'password',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
            'swipes',
        )
```

This serialization of my Profile class returns just a URL for 'swipes' (e.g. "[host]/swipe/1").

I know this kind of the opposite of how a foreign key relationship is supposed to work, but is there a way for me to serialize this swipe information to display, for example, the direction of the swipe instead of just a URL to the swipe itself?

When serializing a Swipe, I can get the serialization of an associated profile to work by adding "user = ProfileSerializer()". However, when I try to add "swipes = SwipeSerializer()" to my code, the swipes field goes from displaying a list of the URLs to an empty map ("{}").

Is this a problem with the fact that I'm "reversing" the foreign key relationship? How can I can get this serialization to work?

Comment: Can you add the code for model Profile?

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Profile is essentially just a Django AbstractUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the default serialization of the `swipes` field in `ProfileSerializer`. However, you need to be careful that the serializer you specify doesn't then have a field for `user` that will end up recursively serializing each other.

Basically you'd need something like:

```
class PureSwipeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...


class PureProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    swipes = PureSwipeSerializer(many=True)
    ...

class SwipeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = PureProfileSerializer(many=False)
    ...
```